# How do I exclude some table columns in the kartik gridview from being exported in pdf and excel files?

Tags: php, yii2, kartik-v

I am using kartik gridview to render my table data. When exporting the table data in excel or pdf formats, I only want certain rows to be included. How do I filter out the columns I don't need exported?

Shown below is part of the code in the grid:

```
 'exportConfig' => [
   GridView::EXCEL => [
            'label' => 'EXCEL',
            'showHeader' => true,
            'showPageSummary' => false,
            'showFooter' => false,
            'showCaption' => false,
            'filename' => $filename,
            'alertMsg' => 'The Excel export file will be generated for download.',    
            'mime' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
            'config' => [
                'worksheet' => $worksheet,
                'cssFile' => ''
            ]
   ]
   GridView::PDF => [
            'label' => 'PDF',
            'filename' => $config['filename'],
            'showHeader' => true,
            'showPageSummary' => false,
            'showFooter' => false,
            'showCaption' => false,
            'alertMsg' => 'The PDF export file will be generated for download.',
            'mime' => 'application/pdf',
            'config' => [
                'mode' => 'c',
                'format' => 'A4-L',
                'destination' => 'D',
                'marginTop' => 20,
                'marginBottom' => 20,
                'cssInline' => '.kv-wrap{padding:20px;}' .
                    '.kv-align-center{text-align:center;}' .
                    '.kv-align-left{text-align:left;}' .
                    '.kv-align-right{text-align:right;}' .
                    '.kv-align-top{vertical-align:top!important;}' .
                    '.kv-align-bottom{vertical-align:bottom!important;}' .
                    '.kv-align-middle{vertical-align:middle!important;}' .
                    '.kv-page-summary{border-top:4px double #ddd;font-weight: bold;}' .
                    '.kv-table-footer{border-top:4px double #ddd;font-weight: bold;}' .
                    '.kv-table-caption{font-size:1.5em;padding:8px;border:1px solid #ddd;border- 
                     bottom:none;}',
                'methods' => [
                    'SetHeader' => [
                        ['odd' => self::setHeader($config['centerContent']), 'even' => 
                         self::setHeader($config['centerContent'])]
                    ],
                    'SetFooter' => [
                        ['odd' => self::setFooter(), 'even' => self::setFooter()]
                    ],
                ],
                'options' => [
                    'title' => $config['title'],
                    'subject' => $config['subject'],
                    'keywords' => $config['keywords'],
                ],
                'contentBefore'=>$config['contentBefore'],
                'contentAfter'=>$config['contentAfter']
            ]
   ]
 ],
```

Comment: [You need to add specific html class in column options](https://demos.krajee.com/grid#grid-export)

Comment: You should be use visible attribute for column to toggle it.

Answer (score 0):

use following code for columns you want hide in export

`hiddenFromExport'=>true`